# multiple grouping a JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, grouping

I want to get a new JSON object from this:

`(group by "a" & group by "b" field with sum "d" and with count(objects))`

```
var json = [
    {"a":121, "b":212, "c":"0", "d":100},
    {"a":121, "b":212, "c":"0", "d":300},
    {"a":121, "b":210, "c":"0", "d":200},
    {"a":120, "b":210, "c":"0", "d":300}
    ];

var new_json = [
    {"a":121, "b":212, "c":"0", "d":400, "count":2},
    {"a":121, "b":210, "c":"0", "d":200, "count":1},
    {"a":120, "b":210, "c":"0", "d":300, "count":1}
    ];
```

Is it possible without underscore js? Can you help me?

Comment: Yes it is possible, please show us what you tried, and post a demo to reproduce your particular issue.

Comment: @elclanrs what he wants can you elaborate?

Comment: BTW, none of what you've shown is JSON. JSON is a string representation. You're actually dealing with just plain ol' objects. Don't add to the confusion.

Comment: In any case, I'm deleting these now, because they are in no way helpful to the OP.  It just bugs me when people troll threads with useless technicalities.

Answer (score 1):

As per OP, please find the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4vxty433/1/)**

```
var json = [
    {"a":121, "b":212, "c":"0", "d":100},
    {"a":121, "b":212, "c":"0", "d":300},
    {"a":121, "b":210, "c":"0", "d":200},
    {"a":120, "b":210, "c":"0", "d":300}
];

function compare(first, second) {
  if (first.a < second.a && first.b < second.b)
     return -1;
  if (first.a > second.a && first.b > second.b)
     return 1;
  return 0;
}


var sorted = json.sort(compare);
var length = sorted.length;
for (var i = 0; i < length; i+=1) {
    sorted[i].count = 1;
}

for (var i = 0; i < sorted.length-1; i+=1) {
    for(var j = i+1; j < sorted.length; j += 1) {
        if(sorted[i].a === sorted[j].a) {
            sorted[i].count += 1;
            sorted[i].d += sorted[j].d;
            sorted.splice(j, 1);
        }
    }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(sorted, ' ', 2));
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "a": 121,
    "b": 212,
    "c": "0",
    "d": 400,
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "a": 121,
    "b": 210,
    "c": "0",
    "d": 200,
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "a": 120,
    "b": 210,
    "c": "0",
    "d": 300,
    "count": 1
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for you too sarbbottam!
Now i just need to find out which is the faster way, because it is very large object. I will testing speed of your samples.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [Alasql](http://github.com/agershun/alasql) library.

```
var res = alasql('SELECT a,b,c,SUM(d) AS d,COUNT(*) AS [count] FROM ? \
                  GROUP BY a,b,c',[json]);
```

Try this example [at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agershun/2u54cpuy/1/).

Formally, this example does not use Underscore, but I put it here, because you can group and sum multiple columns in one line.

Answer (score 0):

This version iterates all entries using [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) creating or updating an entry in a tmp object using a compound key: `entry.a + ":" + entry.b`

Once complete, it maps the array of generated keys into an array of values and returns the result.

Code:

```
var json = [
    {"a":121, "b":212, "c":"0", "d":100},
    {"a":121, "b":212, "c":"0", "d":300},
    {"a":121, "b":210, "c":"0", "d":200},
    {"a":120, "b":210, "c":"0", "d":300}
    ];

function calcSums(entries) {    
    var result = {};
    entries.forEach(function(val) {
        // Generate a key using val.a and val.b
        var key = val.a + ":" + val.b;

        // If an entry doesn't exist for the key, initialize a new one, otherwise
        // use the existing entry
        result[key] = result[key] || { a: val.a, b: val.b, c: val.c, d: 0, count: 0 };

        result[key].d += val.d;
        result[key].count++;
    });

    // Map an array of keys into an array of values    
    return Object.keys(result).map(function(key) {
        return(result[key]);
    });
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(calcSums(json), null, 2));
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    "a": 121,
    "b": 212,
    "c": "0",
    "d": 400,
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "a": 121,
    "b": 210,
    "c": "0",
    "d": 200,
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "a": 120,
    "b": 210,
    "c": "0",
    "d": 300,
    "count": 1
  }
]
```

[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LvzLo59m/3/)